# Send online photo with Telegram Messenger API with HTML mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm creating a bot for Telegram Messenger with Python.

I'm using the following function :

```
def telegram_bot_sendtexHTML(bot_message):

    bot_token = 'token'
    bot_chatID = 'id'
    send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + bot_chatID + '&parse_mode=HTML&text=' + bot_message
    response = requests.get(send_text)

    return response.json()
```

I have a list of images online (with URL link) I want to send using this function.

For example : https://media.wordpress.com/picture1.jpg

How can I insert this lik in my function in order to being able to send directly the picture (and not the link of the picture) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sendPhoto` instead of the `sendMessage` method. 
The required parameters are nicely described in the [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto).

I've altered your `telegram_bot_sendtexHTML` function to a `telegram_bot_sendImage`;

```py
def telegram_bot_sendImage(caption, url):

    bot_token = ''
    bot_chatID = ''
    send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + '/sendPhoto?chat_id=' + bot_chatID + '&parse_mode=HTML&caption=' + caption + '&photo=' + url
    response = requests.get(send_text)

    return response.json()

telegram_bot_sendImage('Cool image!', 'http://placehold.it/200x200')
```

[image]