# How can I send image with text using telegram bot API?

Tags: python, api, telegram

I'm trying to send a message to telegram using Telegram API bot.

I want to make a GET request, that will send both text and image to my telegram channel.

Now fetch looks like that:

```js
telegram_msg = requests.get('https://api.telegram.org/<botname>:botAPI/sendMessage?chat_id=<chat_id>=some text')
```

How can I include an image that is located [here](https://www.ixbt.com/img/n1/news/2022/3/1/62342d1404eb2_large.jpg) and send both text and image in one message?

Thank you for your help.

UPD: I can send image using sendPhoto, but how can I combine these two requests into one? So that I can send both image and text?

Comment: I don't know much about the telegrambot API, but after a quick search I found the send media method, that might be what you are looking for ? https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.sendMedia

Comment: Thank you, but how can I use it? Documentation doesn't make any sense(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send online photo with Telegram Messenger API with HTML mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61246523/send-online-photo-with-telegram-messenger-api-with-html-mode)

Comment: You need the `caption` field to add text to a image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use caption parameter in [sendPhoto](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto) method

```
telegram_msg = requests.get('https://api.telegram.org/bot<botAPI>/sendPhoto?chat_id=<chat_id>&caption=some text')
```

Answer (score 5):

After using [@BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather) to get your API token

```py
import requests
chat_id = '<chat_id>'
token = '<token>'
msg = "Send text with photo "
img_uri = "https://www.ixbt.com/img/n1/news/2022/3/1/62342d1404eb2_large.jpg"
telegram_msg = requests.get(f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendPhoto?chat_id={chat_id}&caption={msg}&photo={img_uri}')
print(telegram_msg)
print(telegram_msg.content)
```

[Post result with text and image in Telegram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8l6Ly.jpg)

Comment: Is it possible to send a local photo? For example uploading it from local drive / NAS etc.